# Getting Specs2 to shows results with Gradle

Tags: gradle, specs2

Having trouble getting Specs2 to work with Gradle, and the examples/advice I'm seeing around the place isn't really helping. The tests appear to be running, it's just that results aren't turning up (neither in the console nor the html report). What am I missing?

All the spec classes are decorated with

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
```

The build.gradle looks as follows (java project, with scala/specs2 tests):

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'scala'

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
  compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.7'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.5'
  testCompile "org.specs2:specs2-core_2.11:3.7.2"
  testCompile "org.specs2:specs2-junit_2.11:3.7.2"
  testCompile "org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2"
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven {
    url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"
  }
  maven {
    url "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
  }
}

test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}

test {
  onOutput { descriptor, event ->
    logger.lifecycle("Test: " + descriptor + " produced standard out/err: " + event.message )
  }
}
```

Based on what I'm reading and my own (admittedly limited) knowledge of gradle, this should work. What am I missing?

Edit:
Updating the specs2 version (changed above) helped.

Comment: Could the problem be solved by using a more recent version of specs2 (3.7.2 is the latest)? Are junit tests running fine in your setup?

Comment: /facepalm. Well, that helped - now I'm at least getting results outputted in HTML. It was working fine via intellij, so I didn't even consider that it might be a problem with the specs2 version. Am I missing something for console output, because from what I understood of the examples, the above should also output to console?

Comment: I don't know how to pass arguments to gradle but if you pass `console junitxml` as specs2 arguments (or maybe `-Dspecs2.console` `-Dspecs2.junitxml`) you should get a console output.